# how to show alert in html page when text change in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box, and I wanted an alert when the text changes but now, the problem is, when I write 11 it show two times alert.

```
    function onChangeText(){

       alert("Please show update buttons"); 

    }
```

Comment: mean i want to enter 1 in input  field then it shows alert one time but if i anter 11 then it shows alert 2 times i want to show it only one time when value is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this : [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPPD7/)

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert('Hello');">​
```

Comment: but in this it shows alert when i click on web page after entering data i want that when data is enterd after that it should show alert not on clicking on page

Comment: @user1736928 it is because it alerts when it is focused off the input box, it only alerts if the text is changed in the input field

Comment: @user1736928, so whats your requirement.. when do you need message ... either get on onchange, onblur or onchangetext, but The onBlur event is fired when you have moved away from an object without necessarily having changed its value. The onChange event is only called when you have changed the value of the field.

Comment: mean after i have changed text i have to click  any where to show alert

Comment: yes i want to after change values but it show alert wihtoud clicking on any other object

Comment: press tab, don't click anywhere.. i didn't understand without focus on another object how will you get these event?...

Comment: @user1736928 I've addressed that issue in my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try onkey up instead of onchange

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="onChangeText()" />
```

Comment: I couldn't find your two times case with 11

Answer (score 0):

You can call your javascript `onblur` instead of `onchange` like

```
<input type="text" onblur="onChangeText();">​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value != '') onChangeText();">​
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `focusout`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQeJH/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be create global timeout variable, bind listener to the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input) event. The callback function would reset [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and check if previous event occured specified time ago (500ms in example).

As you might have noticed, examples with *onchange* execute after clicking on the other element. This is default behaviour for *change* event. *Input* behaves different.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Klaster_1/3byVb/

```
var timeout;
$("input").on("input", function(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(function(){
        if(value.length){
            alert(value);
        }
    },500);
});​
```